# MySQL Query Not returning all rows with this query

Tags: mysql, row

I have the following query:

```
SELECT 
  IF(COUNT(*) > 0, COUNT(*), '0') AS Found, 
  IF(NWLat, NWLat, '0')           AS NWLat, 
  IF(NWLon, NWLon, '0')           AS NWLon, 
  IF(SELat, SELat, '0')           AS SELat, 
  IF(SELon, SELon, '0')           AS SELon 
FROM s 
WHERE s.ci = '4' 
  AND s.snf = 'Ch'
GROUP BY s.sid
```

Right now it returns rows for matched query.  However, when nothing is matched, it returns nothing.  How can I make it return "Found: 0, NWLat: 0, NWLon: 0, SELat: 0, SELon: 0" if nothing is found?

Comment: Why it should be 2 rows? you are doing `COUNT(*)`, I think you might need a `GROUP BY` but `GROUP BY` what??

Comment: Plus those second third IF statements, what are you comparing there? Are those boolean values? e.g. NwlAT? NWlon?

Comment: Which rows are not returned?

Comment: @bonCodigo, I was just displaying the value or '0' if none... is there a better way to do this?

Comment: @sorencito, quick question: I am doing GROUP BY and it displays what I want when the search matches... however, it doesn't display anything when the search comes up empty. Is there a way to make it return "Found :0, NWLat: 0, NWLon: 0, SELat: 0, SELon: 0"?

Comment: @Mahmoud Gamal, I edited the question.

Comment: It's easiest to handle this programatically. If no rows are returned then you know all those values are zero, so display that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better, not to do so in MySQL. SQL is not about that. From your front end application if your query doesn't return any records, then you can easily print 0's.

**However**, if you need to do this any way you can do this:

```
SELECT 
  IF(COUNT(*) > 0, COUNT(*), '0') AS Found, 
  IF(NWLat, NWLat, '0')           AS NWLat, 
  IF(NWLon, NWLon, '0')           AS NWLon, 
  IF(SELat, SELat, '0')           AS SELat, 
  IF(SELon, SELon, '0')           AS SELon 
FROM s 
WHERE s.ci = '4' 
  AND s.snf = 'Ch'
GROUP BY s.sid 
UNION ALL
SELECT
  '0' AS Found, 
  '0' AS NWLat, 
  '0' AS NWLon, 
  '0' AS SELat, 
  '0' AS SELon 
FROM s 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 
      IF(COUNT(*) > 0, COUNT(*), '0') AS Found, 
      IF(NWLat, NWLat, '0')           AS NWLat, 
      IF(NWLon, NWLon, '0')           AS NWLon, 
      IF(SELat, SELat, '0')           AS SELat, 
      IF(SELon, SELon, '0')           AS SELon 
    FROM s 
    WHERE s.ci = '4' 
    AND s.snf = 'Ch'
    GROUP BY s.sid
);
```

**Demos:**

- [If there is records](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/75c29/1).
- [IF there is no records returned](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2efdb/1), and this will give you:

  ```
  | FOUND | NWLAT | NWLON | SELAT | SELON |
  -----------------------------------------
  |     0 |     0 |     0 |     0 |     0 |
  ```

Answer (score 0):

FYI, if you genuinely have a`COUNT(*)` Of 0, this means that there are *NO* rows for that group, so there will never be a row in the result.  Your `IF(COUNT(*) > 0, COUNT(*), '0')` won't do you any good, because there will be no row in which to show a 0.

As to the other ifs, I suspect you want something like this:
`SELECT (case when NWLat is null then 0 else NWLat end)

. . .

GROUP BY sid, (case when NWLat is null then 0 else NWLat end),` etc.

This will allow those to be included in the group and will allow 0 to show as a group.

Answer (score 0):

For you last comment, do you want to try this? here you con't have to count all to determine if you have the records that you need based on the condition.

```
SELECT     
case when NWLat is null then 0 else NWLat end AS NWLat, 
case when NWLon is null then 0 else NWLon end AS NWLon,
case when SELat is null then 0 else SELat end AS SELat,
case when SELon is null then 0 else SELon end AS SELon
FROM S
where NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
             FROM s
             WHERE ci = 4 and snf = 'Ch')
GROUP BY sid, NWLon, SELat, SELon;
```

Comment: This will not return anything if there's no record ;) but if I change to `not exits` then it will return a true where OP can do what he needs...but it's really *odd*..

Comment: Yes, you are right. But, that is what the OP wants. If there is no records at all, he wants 0's. See his post after edit: *`when nothing is matched, it returns nothing. How can I make it return "Found: 0, NWLat: 0, NWLon: 0, SELat: 0, SELon: 0" if nothing is found?`* I know this weried and it is best to do this pragmatically but I thought I should point out to that.